# Error upon exporting to .png

Tags: export, png, krita

When exporting an image from Krita, I get the error stating that I can only save grayscale and RGB images, convert first. I searched the menus and couldn't find an option to convert it that worked. I also tried flattening all of the layers into one, which didn't work either.

How would I convert my image to make it so I can export a .png?

Comment: Hi CraftedCart, If you are seeking technical assistance with an application, please try the application manufacture's web site. Unfortunately, GD.SE is not designed to handle issues regarding technical support. My only guess is that you're working in CMYK color mode and the program wants you to convert to RGB before exporting to a PNG file.

Comment: @AndrewH I'm using RGBA, and an sRGB profile. I tried a greyscale profile (It also had an alpha channel), as well as some other RGB profiles (Which all had alpha). If it is the alpha channel stuffing up the export, (Since it asks for just RGB), then I'm a bit confused, I thought PNGs could handle transparency.

Comment: I am not sure then, yes PNG files do support transparencies. I do not have any experience with Krita and I am not sure many others on this site do either. That Is why I suggest you ask on the [Krita Forum](https://forum.kde.org/index.php). You should also check out their [export wiki](https://userbase.kde.org/Krita/Manual/ImportExport). You will also get better help if you include the error message verbatim when posting an error issue online.

Comment: @AndrewH Ah, the wiki. Didn't notice this before "PNG for example can't take higher than 16bit." I'm using 32 bit...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Converting the image from 32 bit to 16 bit solved this issue. The error message was misleading

Comment: Why on earth were you working in 32 bit? why on earth would you work at 16 bit? Why don't you work in 8 bit like most of the world (there's no reason to go above that unless you have a 10 or 12 bit monitor that can actually display higher than 8bit color)